# optional command line arguments for client program in c++

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have to modify this code which needs 2 command line argument

```
  if (argc == 3){
   host = argv[1];
    port = atoi(argv[2]);
      else {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage error: incorrect number of arguments\n");
```

to have 3 optional command line argument in any order (username,the server host num,the server port num ).I write it this way but it won't work.could somebody please help me to figure out what to do.thanks

```
  if (argc<1 || argc>4)
    fprintf(stderr, "usage error: incorrect number of arguments\n");
else 
    for(int i=1;i<=argc;i++)
    {
        if (strcmp( argv[i],"-u"==0 )
             username=argv[i];
        if(strcmp(argv[i],"-p"==0)
            port=atoi(argv[i]);
        if (strcmp(avrgv[i],"-h"==0)
            host=(argv[i]);
```

Comment: Probably because you're missing a `)` around your `strcmp(argv[i], ".."==0)` lines...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt), it's purpose-built for handling command line arguments in a consistent way, something which is notoriously difficult to do correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the index to get value of the argument bypassing the options. e.g. modify your code like this.

```
   if (argc<1 || argc>4)
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s -u username\n", argv[0]);
    else 
        for(int i=1;i<=argc;i += 2)
        {
            if (strcmp( argv[i],"-u")==0 )
                 username=argv[i + 1];
```

Also you'd better define `username` as a `char` array and copy argument value into it, so you can modify it directly, like this:

```
char username[NAME_LEN + 1];                            // +1 for tailing '\0'
strncpy(username, argv[i + 1], NAME_LEN);
```